# problems with using jqueryfiletree

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

So when I open this webpage I created while running Firebug I receive this message `missing ) after argument list` referencing this part of the javascript (the first occurrence) `fuction() {`

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<%--<script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jqueryFileTree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Scripts/jqueryFileTree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        fuction() {
            $('#fileTreeDemo').fileTree({ 
                root: 'C:/Test/Pictures', 
                script:'Scripts/connectors/jqueryFileTree.aspx' 
             },
            function(file) {
                alert(file);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Now am I doing something wrong, forgetting something, is it possible that the `jqueryFileTree.js` contains the problem?

working with this in Visual Studios is showing warning markers on the `:` following `root` and `script` among a few other warnings. I can list them all if it would be useful.

Please let me know if anything is unclear or if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fuction` should be `function`:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fileTreeDemo').fileTree({
            root: 'C:/Test/Pictures',
            script: 'Scripts/connectors/jqueryFileTree.aspx'
        },
        function (file) {
            alert(file);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Sometimes it takes second pair of eyes ;)